# VBA Connect from excel to Access database file placed on sharepoint

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint, vba

I got a little problem with connecting to .accdb file.

 Couple words of explanation 

I have excel file and access database 

Access database is located on sharepoint folder. 

Excel file is located on my desktop 

Usually there is no problem but sometimes i got -2147467259 error when trying to connect to .accdb file form excel. Error description is something like "String "connection string" is not a valid path..." (this is only part of description) 

 When this error occurs i can still open sharepoint site using web browser and access all files in folder. 

 Error dissapears when i open database file using browser.

 

 My connection string is `cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\some\path\to\folder\on\sharepoint\Database.accdb ;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxx"`

Does anyone knows why it's not working from time to time?

Comment: Well, if the path is not valid, and you're not sharing the actual path... I'd say it's this space here:`db ;`. But who knows, I'm debugging an imaginary path.

Comment: But it's working like 95% of the time. I can save and download data to/from database. Just sometimes it won't connect and i don't know why.